# How to get port in FTP protocol from passive mode?

Tags: ftp, port, passive-mode

When I entered passive mode in FTP, I have got:

**227 Entering Passive Mode (213,180,204,183,230,205).**

First 4 numbers are the IP addresses, but what are the two last?

*Are they two ports?*

Answer (score 64, accepted):

the last two are: p1 and p2 from RFC of ftp:
http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html

to get port, use:

p1 * 256 + p2, then connect to this port

Comment: Thank you! You helped me to solve my job's problem this night :)

Comment: How to connet to that port? what should I write on cmd?

Comment: What the source documentation of the (p1 * 256 + p2) rule ? I've searched this in the RFC959 document, and I've founded nothing!

Answer (score 22):

the port number is a 16-bit value between 0 and 65535
due to some constraints the authors have decided that all numbers between commas should be 8-bit (between 0 and 255). Thus, the 16-bit port number is represented with 2 8-bit numbers.

In your case the port number will be 230 * 256 + 205 = 59085

Comment: @bazis well-advanced answer :)